# What does Chocolatey consider essential information?

Tags: chocolatey

The Chocolatey documentation describes the `-r, --limitoutput, --limit-output` flags as "Limit the output to essential information".

I'm using it with the upgrade command:

```
choco upgrade all --whatif --limitoutput
```

and get this output:

```
7zip.commandline|16.02.0.20170209|16.02.0.20170209|false
7zip.portable|18.1|18.1|false
atom|1.23.3|1.24.0|false
autohotkey.portable|1.1.28.00|1.1.28.00|false
bulkrenameutility|3.0.0.1|3.0.0.1|false
bulkrenameutility.install|3.0.0.1|3.0.0.1|false
calibre|3.17.0|3.17.0|false
chocolatey|0.10.8|0.10.8|false
```

The first three columns appear to be:

Package name | installed version | available version

But what's the last column? I initially thought the boolean was for upgrade available, but Atom has an upgrade available yet it's false, so I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information that you are seeing is as follows:

`Package Name | Installed Package Version | Available Package Version | Is Package Pinned?`

This last part is an important piece of information, and you can find out more information about it [here](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-pin), but the gist of it is:

> Pin a package to suppress upgrades.
>
> This is especially helpful when running choco upgrade for all
>   packages, as it will automatically skip those packages. Another
>   alternative is choco upgrade --except="pkg1,pk2".

The command that you are running is actually very similar to the [`choco outdated`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-outdated) command, which actually includes a legend which explains each column in the output.